# I get cookie from Postman but not on Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie with name of `auth`, includes user's id signed with jwt. I dont really see the `auth` cookie on Chrome when I hit `http://localhost:5000/` I only see these two; 
 
[image: chrome]

But the thing is, when I hit the same route with **Postman**, I get `auth` cookie in the console.
By the way I console the cookie with `req.cookies`

And there is my `server.js`;

```
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import connectDB from './utils/db.js';
import { notFound, errorHandler } from './middleware/errorMiddleware.js';
const app = express();
dotenv.config();
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import userRoutes from './routes/userRoutes.js';
import cors from 'cors';

app.use(cors());

connectDB();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hi');
  console.log(req.cookies);
});

app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);

app.use(notFound);
app.use(errorHandler);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server is listening on PORT 5000'));
```

And here is my `register` function where I first set the cookie;

```
// desc     Register User
// route    /api/users/register
// access   Public
const register = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  let { name, email, password } = req.body;

  const isUserExists = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (isUserExists) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error('Invalid e-mail or password');
  }

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

  const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password,
  });

  const token = generateToken(user._id);
  res.cookie('auth', token, {
    httpOnly: false,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3, // 3 dayss
  });

  res.status(201);

  res.json({
    _id: user._id,
    name: user.name,
    email: user.email,
    isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `fetch` API in your client side code? Try using `credentials: 'include',` there. Otherwise the cookies wont set in your browser.

```
fetch('https://example.com', {
 ...
  credentials: 'include'
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included

Comment: I installed react, it sets the cookie and I see it in the application in chrome dev-tools, now there is another problem, even If i send wrong user credentials, user info does not return -just like it should be- but it still sets the cookie... how is that even possible